# Vite Build Missing css file from npm package

Tags: css, reactjs, node.js, typescript

I am attempting to build an application to upload to a server directory. I don't get any errors when building, however when I try to visit my website I get a 404 error telling me that one of my css files was not found.  That css file is part of an npm package (which I manage).

When I check my sources for the page I can see there is an assets folder with an index.js file but there is no index.css file in this folder (my other repos all build with the index.css file).

I am running this command to build my project.

```
"build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development npm run build",
```

My vite.config.js looks like:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import basicSsl from '@vitejs/plugin-basic-ssl'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), basicSsl()],
  server: {
    https: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

and my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

The project is build to a dist folder with the following structure:

```
-assets
--index.js
-index.html
```

My other projects that do work get built with an `index.css` file in the `assets` folder.  I can't say for sure that this is the problem.

I'm not even sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue. Any advice would be appreciated.